# Athena Connector does not show any datasets under AWSCatalog

Tags: powerbi, odbc, amazon-athena

I am trying to get some production data from AWS Athena into Power BI for reporting purposes. I created a test connector using the Simba Athena ODBC 64 bit connector and was able to view and access the relevant data.

However, when I created a separate connector to get the production data (using the same steps as the test connector), I am unable to see any datasets under the AWS Catalog section. Below is a snip of how this looks in Power BI.

[Image of results using the connector to ingest Prod Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0W7v.png).

Compared to the above, below is a snip of how the test connector looks when trying to get data from test environment.

[Results using the Test connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl4m2.png)

I'd appreciate if someone with similar experience or knowledge of how to overcome this issue can assist here.

I set up 2 separate connectors to test and ingest data from Athena into Power BI. While the test connector only uses high level information such as S3 output, region, and log in credentials, the Prod connector has all other relevant information such as the schema and workspace.

I have also ensured that I reset my global settings to ensure that only the correct credentials are used when attempting to ingest data using the different connections.

Regards

Shiv